# Is there a definite term(or phrase) for the concept "This thing I don't know about probably works perfectly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, I work as a stock trader and at times people talk about some combination of indicators or some chat pattern I don't know about and I immediately think "This must be it, this is why my trades weren't working. If I master this concept I can win". I know this won't work in trading nevertheless this feeling comes in many other occasions too. I just wanted to ask if it has a term in English.

Comment: ...like some kind of _magic formula_?

Comment: sample sentence(s) please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for a "silver bullet" that will solve your intractable problem as a phrase or an idiom.  You could also be looking for a specific "panacea" that will work on all occasions in a single word.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/silver+bullet

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/panacea

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of panacea but somehow it seemed unsuitable for situation. "Silver bullet" seems to fit perfectly.